# Inkscape changing last imported SVG colors when importing a new SVG

Tags: inkscape, svg

I am using Inkscape 1.1 (2021-05-23) to create some templates for a reMarkable 2 Paper Tablet. When I import an SVG into the canvas reusing pre-existing work, the colors are retained. However, the next SVG I import shows up properly, but the previous imported SVGs change their colors making it so I have to go back through and futz again with ungrouping, and then changing each little color. How does one avoid this thing? Has anyone else experienced this?

SVG Assets in question.

- [DrainSmith's Genesys Dispensery: CRB Vector Images](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/raqr7usuzwizglm/AABensdp7kz0r0NA5VJ0ZhCVa/Graphic%20Design%20Resources/Vector%20Images/CRB?dl=0&subfolder_nav_tracking=1)

GitLab: Inkscape Issue Report

- https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inbox/-/issues/5282

Comment: I believe this may be attributed to the SVG's importing have similarly named elements an the newly imported ones overwrite the existing element's attributes.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Try this instead. Don't import the SVGs.  Open each as a new document. Then select, and Copy and paste one into the other.  It's hard to answer this for sure without access to the SVG files.

Comment: @BillyKerr, I added the link to the SVG's in question.

Comment: I did try the copy and paste method as well, same result, if not some different results as well.

Comment: I see the problem. I think it's probably a bug because of the styles not having unique names. However that shouldn't really matter, but it causes all sorts of issues in Inkscape 1.0 and later. I think it might be a bug because I can easily click and drag the SVGs into Inkscape 0.92.3 without the problem appearing. [see example](https://imgur.com/15Q8QlJ).  Maybe get a copy of an older version to make the edit.

Comment: Totally unrelated, but I note that that "MinionRivalBlock.svg" has been saved with the wrong file extension. It's a PDF.